# Get sub objects of sub objects collections

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am having difficulty with using Linq against a dbContext, getting the counts of objects where collections of child object of child objects have particular highest values.

I have the classes Request, Event, User. My simplified object graph is like this:-

```
Request                        Event                  User
  |                             |                      |-> Username
  |-> EventsCollection          |-> Description
  |-> User                      |-> WhenDone
```

I'm sure the domain model could be altered but regardless, using the current structure
what I want is the count of the number of requests by a particular user where the most recent event has a particular description.

I initially thought something like the following would give me the value I am looking for

```
value = _db.Requests.Where(r => r.User.UserName.Equals("username") &&  r.Events.OrderByDescending(e => e.WhenDone).First().Description.Equals( "description")).Count();
```

However on running this I get an error 'First' can only be used as a final query operation changing it I get other errors such as unsupported method etc.

I'm guessing I ought to use sub queries but haven't been able to get the syntax right.

Any pointers to useful sources or suggested solutions would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int count = _db.Requests.Where(r => r.User.UserName == "username")
               .Select(r => 
                   r.Events.OrderByDescending(e => e.WhenDone).FirstOrDefault())
               .Count(r => r != null && r.Description == "description");
```

Comment: Spot on, worked first time, exactly what I was after! Thanks!